# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE isn't granted after allowing if it was denied before (Android 9,10)

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm using Google Pixel 2 with Android 10. My application demands a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for writing some files to external storage. It's works fine if I allow the permission when system dialog appears at first. BUT when writing permissions dialog was denied for the first time and confirmed for the second time the writing permissions is not granted until application restarts. 
This problem reproduces only on Android 9 and 10.

1. The permission requests using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, WRITE_PERM_REQ_CODE);`
2. On permission result handling using

```
if (requestCode == WRITE_PERM_REQ_CODE) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 0){
     //SAVE FILE CODE
   }
}
```

3. The folder path for saving obtaining by `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/";`
4. And in manifest file

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
```

minSdk: 16,
targetSdk: 28,
compileSdk: 28

Comment: The permission module has change in Android Q slightly. I think you should check this out https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/device-location

Comment: Based on the Version Flag you should apply required permission or check backward compatitbility.

Comment: it is called storage access framework and it sucks
https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-storage-access-framework-scoped-storage/